# Suppose we have 44 books on Math, 55 books on English and 66 books on History, In how many ways you can put them on your bookshelf?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have $4$ books on Math, $5$ books on English and $6$ books on History. In how many ways you can put them on your bookshelf if you want :- 
$1)$ The first book is a math book. 
$2)$ All math books are at the beginning. 
$3)$ Math and English books will stay together. 
$4)$ The first book and the last book are both Math books.

(I'm completely lost with this problem. If someone can give me an explanation that would be great.)

I know that we have $3$ subjects so there are $3$! Or $6$ possibilities and for $4$ math books we have $4!$ or $24$ ways to order. When it is $5$ English books we have $5!$ or $120$ ways to order. If it is $6$ history books we have $6!$ Or $720$ ways to order. So I think the answer is $6 \times 24 \times 120 \times 720=12,441,600$ ways to order the books .

Comment: (2) and (4) contradict each other. If the first and last books are math books, then all math books cannot be at the begnning

Comment: I suppose he meant to find the answers for each cases of $(1),(2),(3),(4)$

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: you have asked the same question twice !!! See: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3893411

Comment: Please do not ask your question again to receive more attention.

Comment: "I know that we have 3 subjects so there are 3! Or 6 possibilities "  Possibilities of what?  What question asks about the the order of the *subjects* where each subject must have a position.  No question asks about that so that isn't relevant.  Actually *think* what the questions are specifying and adjust your answers on that.

Comment: " So I think the answer is 6×24×120×720=12,441,600 ways to order the books ."  There are 4 different questions.  Which one are you asking.  You have asssume that all the books of a subject must be group together.  And you reason correctly for that case... but *NONE* of the questions was that case.  So you have answered unasked part 5) How many ways if all the books in each subject must be place together.  ... But how would you answer questions 1) through 4) that ask different conditions.

Answer (score 2):

These are $4$ separate homework problems, right? In total we have $15$ books.

$1)$ $4 * 14!$ (First choose any math book, then for each choice, we can order the remaining 14 however we want)

$2)$ $4! * 11!$ (First, order the math books 4! number of ways, then for each ordering, we can order the remaining 11 however we want)

$3)$ Unclear/left as an exercise for the reader.

$4)$ $4 * 3 * 13!$ (First, choose the first book to be a math book, then choose the last book to be a math book, then order the remaining 13 in the middle however we want)

Comment: The $3$rd part is not unclear, for example. You have to show the total number of arrangements such that each of math and english books are kept consecutively .

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if you could interleave the math/english books, or do they have to reside in segregated groups (4 math books followed by 5 english books)

Comment: They have to be grouped together, in any order.

Comment: I agree with Anonymous. That being said, the number of ways to arrange the books so that the math and english books stay together is $7! \cdot 9!$

Comment: Thank you guys for the help.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if the author of the question intended to allow interspersing engllish and math books together.  I'm fairly certain that the intent was that the math books are together and the english books are together.  (But that the history books may or may no be separated by the blocks of math or the block of english books).  But that's a question of english usage; not math. and can be two separate question 3a) $9!*7*6!$ or 3b) $4!5!*2*{8\choose 2}*6!$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for the $3$rd part .

Assume the $4$ Math and $5$ English books to be in a line, as in each arrangement they have to be consecutively placed. Take this to be a block of $9$ books.

In this block the number of ways to arrange the $4$ Math and $5$ English books would be :- $$\frac{9!}{4!*5!} = 126$$

Now this whole block can be placed with $6$ History books in this number of ways :-
$$\frac{7!}{6! * 1!} = 7$$

Add both of these up to get total number of ways in which Math and English books stay together :- $126 + 7 = 133$ .

Comment: "Assume the 4 Math and 5 English books to be in a line, as in each arrangement they have to be consecutively placed."  Why would you assume that?  If the question means the math books must be grouped together and the english books must be grouped together, then the $9$ needn't be together-- we could have some history books between them. If the question means that history and math books must make a block of $9$ there there is no reason to assume that math books and history books can't be interspersed.

Answer (score 1):

1. The first book must be a math book:

There are $4$ choices for that book.

One you choice that math book, there are $14$ books remaining.  They can go in any order.  SO there are $14!$ ways to do that.

So there are $4 \times 14!$ ways to do problem 1).

2. Math books must go first.

There are $4$ math books that must go in any order in the first $4$ positions.  There are $4!$ ways to do that.

There are $11$ books remaining so there are $11!$ ways to do that.

so there are $4!\times 11!$ ways to do that.

....

can you continue?